# Sort list by Alphanumeric with decimal

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, list, sorting

I have a `List<string>` that I need to sort by alphanumeric but it also has a decimal. The sample looks like this:

E11.9
E13.9
E10.9
E11.65
E10.65
E11.69
E13.10
E10.10

The output I need should look like this:
E10.10
E10.65
E10.9
E11.69
E11.9
etc..

I've tried this code:

```
result.Sort((s1, s2) =>
{
    string pattern = "([A-Za-z])([0-9]+)";
    string h1 = Regex.Match(s1, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
    string h2 = Regex.Match(s2, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
    if (h1 != h2)
        return h1.CompareTo(h2);
    string t1 = Regex.Match(s1, pattern).Groups[2].Value;
    string t2 = Regex.Match(s2, pattern).Groups[2].Value;
    return int.Parse(t1).CompareTo(int.Parse(t2));
});
```

But it only seems to sort by the Letter first, then by the digits prior to the decimal place. So this is what I get:
E10.9
E10.65
E10.10
E11.9
E11.69
etc..

Am I missing something in the regex? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does it always start with an `E` or at least always with a single letter?

Comment: Not always `E` but always with a single letter

Comment: "."(dot) symbol not in `[0-9]` interval. So you sort by `E` and then by number befor "."

Comment: And also you should use double.Parse not int. With appropriate cultureinfo decimal separator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you just do this?:

**Test data:**

```
var ls=new List<string>
    {
    "E11.9",
    "E13.9",
    "E10.9",
    "E11.65",
    "E10.65",
    "E11.69",
    "E13.10",
    "E10.10",
    };
```

**Linq:**

```
var result= ls
             .OrderBy (l =>l.Substring(0,1))
             .ThenBy(l =>double.Parse(l.Substring(1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: This would only work if each line starts with the same letter, right? I guess to accomodate for that, you'd want to first order by `l.SubString(0,1)` and `ThenBy(l => double.Parse [...] )`

Comment: What about culture decimal separator ?

Comment: @germi : I update the answer. To answer your question. Yes. But with an order by then by. It will solve it

Comment: @agent5566 : I have update the answer to include the decimal seperation

Comment: Somone posted this answer and then must have deleted it. It seems to work great though: `result = result.OrderBy(x => x.PadRight(10)).ToList();`

Comment: @KieranQuinn this solution wrong for `"E13.9"` and `"E9.0"`

Comment: @Grundy I think it should be ok though, there will always be 2 digits before the decimal

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Arion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670061/1344058):

```
var result = list.OrderBy(l => l[0]).ThenBy(l => double.Parse(l.Substring(1));
```

So first you'd sort by the letter and after that by the number after the letter. In case you need to handle different culture settings in `double.Parse`, you'd have to supply that there. See [MSDN on Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `l.Substring(0,1)` is same `l[0]`? :-)

Comment: Guys, double.Parse will fall if program will run in culture with decimal separator differ `.`, `,` for example

Comment: @agent5566 Correct, I'll add a bit about that to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is `[single-letter][decimal-number]` you can do:

```
var result= list.
              .OrderBy(s => s.Substring(0,1))
              .ThenBy(s => double.Parse(s.Substring(1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

with no need to involve regexes into the story

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ solution without regex:

```
var ordered = from str in result
              let firstChar = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "" : str.Substring(0, 1)
              let decimalPart = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "" : str.Substring(1)
              let numOrNull = decimalPart.TryGetDecimal(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
              orderby firstChar, numOrNull ?? decimal.MaxValue ascending, str ascending
              select str;
result = ordered.ToList();
```

Used this extension to parse the sub-string to decimal:

```
public static decimal? TryGetDecimal(this string item, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    decimal d = 0m;
    bool success = decimal.TryParse(item, NumberStyles.Any, formatProvider, out d);
    if (success) 
        return d;
    else
        return null;
}
```

You should use this extension instead of a local variable in LINQ queries as learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988523/c-sharp-linq-how-is-string1-2-3-parsed-as-an-array#comment46233107_28988762).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with updated regex

```
ls.Sort((a, b) =>
{
    var pattern = new Regex(@"(?<letter>[A-Za-z])(?<number>[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)$");
    var matchA = pattern.Match(a);
    var matchB = pattern.Match(b);
    var compareLetter = matchA.Groups["letter"].Value.CompareTo(matchB.Groups["letter"].Value);
    if (compareLetter != 0) return compareLetter;

    return double.Parse(matchA.Groups["number"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).CompareTo(
            double.Parse(matchB.Groups["number"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           );
});
```