# Convert String To Nullable Integer List

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm wanting to parse a string into a nullable int list in C#

I'm able to convert it to int list bit not a nullable one

```
string data = "1,2";
List<int> TagIds = data.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

say when data will be empty i want to handle that part!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following extension method:

```
public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Then it's simple:

```
List<int?> TagIds = data.Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.TryGetInt32())
    .ToList();
```

I use that extension method always in LINQ queries if the format can be invalid, it's [better than using a local variable and `int.TryParse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16613455/284240) (E. Lippert gave an example, follow link).

Apart from that it may be better to use `data.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead which omits empty strings in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without an extension method?

Comment: @IfeoluwaOsungade: You can call every extension method as a normal static method(`ClassName.MethodName`).