# How to order by descending versions list in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having a list which has some versions in it .

**sample data :**

```
"4.5","2.1","2.2.1","7.5","7.5.3","N/A","2.3.4.5"
```

As you can see the data , i'm trying to sort list by Descending tough `3.8.5` is `invalid`number & `NA` is a invalid one .

**Code :**

```
decimal result;
var sortedVData = vData.OrderByDescending(v => decimal.TryParse(v.vCode, out result) ? Convert.ToDecimal(v.vCode) : decimal.MaxValue);
```

**Output :**  `"NA" , "7.5.3" , '2.3.4.5' , "2.2.1" , '7.5' , '4.5' , '2.1'`

As you see in my else`(:)` condition i'm doing `decimal.MaxValue` to make `NA` to come top if there is invalid value (any string with text) but `2.2.1` should be a exception and should work as number(tough 2.2.1 or any number having multiple decimals a is invalid in version's point of view i want them made conditionally valid  .

**Expected Result :** `"NA" , "7.5.3" , "7.5" , "4.5" ,"2.3.4.5" ,"2.2.1" , "2.1"`

Comment: Maybe use [`Version.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Are you looking for [Natural Sort Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: Post this in Code Golf? ;-)

Comment: what decimal number is 7.5.3 ?

Comment: @WaiHaLee `version` i never knew it . let me give it a try .

Comment: @supercool The easiest way is to implement custom comparer.

Comment: @mybirthname its a versioning convention tough i mentioned in my post its a invalid value .

Comment: @WaiHaLee post this as an answer

Comment: @mybirthname - It won't be any better than the answer [Tim Schmelter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Version.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and this extension method for LINQ queries:

```
public static Version TryGetVersion(this string item)
{
    Version ver;
    bool success = Version.TryParse(item, out ver);
    if (success) return ver;
    return null;
}
```

Then the complete query is simple:

```
var sortedVData = vData
    .Select(v => new { Obj = v, Version = v.vCode.TryGetVersion() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Version != null)    // first all invalid versions
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Version)   // then by version descending
    .Select(x => x.Obj);
```

So actually it would be better to store [versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of strings in your class.

It's [better to use this extension in LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613224/can-i-use-a-tryparse-inside-linq-comparable) than using a local variable.

Comment: @waiHaLee comment helped me to frame what i need & your answer was absolutely spot on & clean .

Comment: `v.vCode.TryGetVersion()` will return null when i have `NA` in the list & end list will have null instead of `NA` on top

Comment: @supercool: No, i have used `.OrderBy(x => x.Version != null)` which moves the invalid versions to the top. You could also use  `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version == null)` or `.OrderBy(x => x.Version == null ? 0 : 1)`. The trick is that a comparison returns `true` or `false` and `true` has a higher value than `false`. That's why `.OrderBy(x => x.Version != null)` moves the valid versions to the bottom. You need `OrderBy` **and** `ThenByDescending` as shown above.

Comment: humm yes i got the ordering part, its clever . when i tried using the same logic in my real code (i'm binding to dropdown , each list item has many entities i.e version etc not given in the sample ) there seem to be a slightest of issue . anyway i'll workaround it . cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Like @WaiHaLee says, you can use Version, and it implements IComparable, so you can just do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[] {"4.5","2.1","2.2.1","7.5","7.5.3",@"N/A","2.3.4.5"};
        foreach(var v in data.OrderByDescending(OrderVersion))
            Console.WriteLine(v);
    }

    private static IComparable OrderVersion(string arg)
    {
        //Treat N/A as highest version
        if (arg == "N/A")
            return new Version(Int32.MaxValue,Int32.MaxValue); 
        return Version.Parse(arg);
    }
```

Comment: This will fail for "11.1.2". <edit> I failed to read correctly </edit>

Comment: appreciate your time . ty

Answer (score 1):

```
public class VersionsComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {

        if (x.ToLower() == @"n/a")
        {
            if (y.ToLower() == @"n/a")
                return 0;

            return -1;
        }

        if (y.ToLower() == @"n/a")
        {
            if (x.ToLower() == @"n/a")
                return 0;

            return 1;
        }

        var verX = Version.Parse(x);
        var verY = Version.Parse(y);

        return verX.CompareTo(verY);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var versions = new[] { "4.5", "2.1", "2.2.1", "7.5", "7.5.3", @"N/A", "2.3.4.5" };


        foreach (var v in versions.OrderByDescending(v => v, new VersionsComparer()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: appreciate your time . ty